# Render PDF on a Blackberry?

Tags: pdf, blackberry, java-me, jasper-reports

We are using Blackberries to display PDF reports. Here are background details on the problem:

- The PDF reports are created using JasperReports.
- Report format can be changed.
- Different report formats are available (as per the feature set of JasperReports).
- The PDF reports are on a website, too, so retaining a single source is ideal.
- The page setup is in Landscape.

Here are the issues we have encountered:

- Users cannot see a full line of text on the Blackberry.
- The size of the PDF and UI makes reading difficult, at best.
- The menu option to convert the PDF to text loses too much formatting to be useful.
- The text is blurry (and too small).

Here are solutions we have thought about:

- Create a second report (not ideal) in text or HTML format.
- Simplify the original report format (not really an option, given the amount of data).

What other options are there for making a report available on the Blackberry, given the constraints of JaserReports, such that the report:

- Is legible?
- Is formatted for readability?
- Displays quickly?

Essentially, we'd like to make sure there are no simple solutions we have overlooked for displaying legible PDFs on Blackberries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We convert TIFFs to PDF for one of our applications, and have had mixed results with BlackBerry PDF viewers. These were our results.

**Working**

The following PDF readers worked for our purposes:

[RepliGo Reader](http://www.cerience.com/products/reader/) v1.1.1.1 - $19.95
Works fine.

[DataViz Documents To Go Premium Edition](http://www.dataviz.com/products/documentstogo/blackberry/keyfeatures_ptg.html) v1.003.001 - $49.99
Works and includes a word wrap option to get the current zoom level to fit the available screen width, by moving text onto subsequent lines. Might fit your needs.

**Non-Working**

The following PDF readers did not work for our purposes:

[BeamReader](http://www.slgmobile.com/beamreader.html) v1.0.8 - $17.99
[BeamSuite](http://www.slgmobile.com/beamsuite.html) v3.0.2 - $49.99
These couldn't open our PDF files ("Unsupported document format"). In addition they did not register as a PDF content handler, required for our application.

[MasterDoc](http://www.dynoplex.com/masterdoc.shtml) - $19.95
[eOffice](http://www.dynoplex.com/eoffice.shtml) - $29.95
These also did not register as a PDF content handler. We had a range of problems with these, including installation issues, and not being able to open any PDFs at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try BeamReader http://www.slgmobile.com/beamreader.html

I hear it's the best at reading PDFs for BlackBerry

Answer (score 1):

How about outputting the file to an RTF or an image file (JPG/GIF), and then viewing them in your web browser?

If that doesn't work well on the native browser, I would focus on viewing the file via some other web browser - for example, Opera Mini.  I know for images it's easier to navigate "big" images in Opera Mini than the native browser.

Answer (score 0):

If your blackberries are on a BES server, couldn't you display the reports as HTML on your corporate intranet? - Then you could email a link to the blackberry and simply browse the report.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert pdf to image via xpdf and than show image. xpdf is a BEST renderer of pdf.