# How to show pdf in blackberry?

Tags: pdf, blackberry

i have to show pdf file in the blackberry by first downloading it from the server. is there any default feature that blackberry provides to show the pdf in blackberry app?
all suggestions will be appreciated...thanx

Comment: Do a stackoverflow search for "+BlackBerry +pdf"   This question has been asked many times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render PDF on a Blackberry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060222/render-pdf-on-a-blackberry)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no default viewer on the BB to show local PDF files (outside the attachments). You will have to use a third party tool (or write your own viewer)... See [this thread](http://forums.crackberry.com/f79/pdf-viewer-21821/) for more info.

One interesting option you can use is have the pdf in a browser accessible location and pass in code the url of the file to the browser - this should open the file using the BB compressed view (the attachments viewer), though it might only be available with BES/BIS, not sure.