# PDF viewer for Blackberry

Tags: pdf, blackberry

I want to make PDF viewer, I tried many open source libraries, but it failed, just as jpedal and  [PDF renderer](http://pdfrend4bb.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) the last one open blank pages, I don't want to use google docs to view the PDF, Is there an easy way to display PDF on my application?

Comment: This has been asked a few times already.  Search for "+Blackberry +pdf" and you will find, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060222/render-pdf-on-a-blackberry