# PDF Viewer Support of BlackBerry 5+

Tags: blackberry, pdf-viewer

I'm developing a BlackBerry version of an iPhone application which requires PDF file viewer. I've googled but find no proper solution. Can anyone suggest me any way to do it?

Your cooperation is highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render PDF on a Blackberry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060222/render-pdf-on-a-blackberry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pluggable PDF renderer. Users may view PDF files via installed Docs To Go trial software. But there is no tool/API for developers to view PDF files.